# CSS animate while dynamically changing translation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, css-animations

I made an SVG bee that needs to fly. I'm successfully using JavaScript to dynamically change the variables `--tranX` and `--tranY` in the CSS `#bee1` (for changing its location).

Those variables are passed to the `100% {}` keyframe in CSS. However, the animation is not working.

Note: I've already successfully got the bee to move by just applying the `transform`, but then the bee would just hop from location to location without animation.

CSS for the bee:

```
#bee1 {
   -webkit-animation: beeMove 500ms ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
  animation: beeMove 500ms ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
  --tranX: 0;
  --tranY: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes beeMove {
  0% {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY)); 
    transform: translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
  }
}
```

JavaScript for moving the bee (called every second):
for

```
 (let bee of bees) {
    bee.style.setProperty('--tranX', Math.random() * 340 + "px");
    bee.style.setProperty('--tranY', Math.random() * 257 + "px");
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/facechomp/3dbv15u6/26/

Comment: Your issue is that `tranX` and `tranY` are scoped to the `#bee1` selector, but you are also using it in the `beeMove` animation defintion, where it is out of scope and therefore the values of `tranX` and `tranY` is undefined.

Comment: Hmm, but that works for `.front-wing` and `.back-wing`! @Terry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, the CSS variables `tranX` and `tranY` are scoped to the `#bee1` selector, and therefore the values are actually not accessible to the animation definition. If you simply want the bee to fly all over the place randomly without going back to its original position, you can update your code to this:

```
const _locationsInterval = 500; // ms
```

And for the CSS:

```
#bee1 {
  transform: translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
  --tranX: 0;
  --tranY: 0;
    background: red;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```js
const _wingsInterval = 500; // ms
const _locationsInterval = 500; // ms
var frontWings = document.getElementsByClassName('front-wing');
var backWings = document.getElementsByClassName('back-wing');
var bees = document.getElementsByClassName('bee');

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// update all bees' wings every _wingsInterval ms
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
setInterval(function() {
  var rotFront = -Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 5);
  for (let wing of frontWings) {
    wing.style.setProperty('--rotFront', rotFront + "deg");
  }
  var rotBack = -Math.round(Math.random() * 20 + 2);
  for (let wing of backWings) {
    wing.style.setProperty('--rotBack', rotBack + "deg");
  }
}, _wingsInterval);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// update all bees' locations every _locationsInterval ms
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
setInterval(function() {
  for (let bee of bees) {
    bee.style.setProperty('--tranX', Math.random() * 340 + "px");
    bee.style.setProperty('--tranY', Math.random() * 257 + "px");
  }
}, _locationsInterval);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.image-contain {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
}

.front-wing {
  -webkit-animation: flapWingFront 60ms ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
  animation: flapWingFront 60ms ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
  --tranX: -52%;
  --tranY: -26%;
  --rotFront: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flapWingFront {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(var(--rotFront)) translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
    transform: rotate(var(--rotFront)) translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
  }
}

.back-wing {
  -webkit-animation: flapWingBack 40ms ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
  animation: flapWingBack 40ms ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
  --btranX: -54%;
  --btranY: -15%;
  --rotBack: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flapWingBack {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) translateX(var(--btranX)) translateY(var(--btranY));
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(var(--btranX)) translateY(var(--btranY));
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(var(--rotBack)) translateX(var(--btranX)) translateY(var(--btranY));
    transform: rotate(var(--rotBack)) translateX(--var(--btranX)) translateY(var(--btranY));
  }
}

#bee1 {
  transform: translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
  --tranX: 0;
  --tranY: 0;
 background: red;
 transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-contain">

  <svg id="bee1" class="bee" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 340 275" width="75" height="50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="a">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#c5c5c7"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c5c5c7" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <path d="M453.56 309.74c-11.86-45.92-22.57-71.57-55.36-100.67-21.86-19.41-40.14-15.15-54.82 12.76.16 1.03.93 6.18 2.32 15.46" id="d"/>
    <path d="M453.52 309.46c-78.71-25.57-114.71-49.86-107.99-72.87" id="b"/>
    <path d="M329.87 244.41c10.67.51 18.19-1.54 20.5-13.36 9.08-46.7-15.06-50.63-24.91-52.94-9.86-2.31-32.31-8.05-41.92-1.55-6.41 4.34-9.41 9.32-8.99 14.94 1.11 4.69 1.8 7.61 2.08 8.78.38 1.62 1.01 3.16 1.87 4.56.33.54-.81-1.33-.69-1.12 1.55 2.53 2.63 5.33 3.17 8.26 1.64 8.8 3.98 14.55 7.02 17.25 19.13 16.95 35.93 14.91 41.87 15.18z" id="e"/>
    <path d="M236.72 232.73l5.12 4.79-6.97 15.88 13.4-14.87-12.88-11.34-7.85 17.15z" id="f"/>
    <path d="M262.3 156.27c-.45 1.33-1.37 4.11-1.83 5.45a1.22 1.22 0 0 1-1.61.76c-3.15-1.2-11.39-4.37-14.53-5.58a1.358 1.358 0 0 1-.8-1.7c.44-1.33 1.37-4.11 1.81-5.44.22-.67.96-1.02 1.62-.77l14.53 5.58c.68.26 1.04 1.01.81 1.7z" id="g"/>
    <path d="M259.43 179.58c-.91.41-2.58 1.16-3.5 1.55a1 1 0 0 1-1.37-.62c-.91-2.8-3.25-10.14-4.16-12.95-.19-.62.1-1.28.69-1.54.92-.41 2.59-1.15 3.5-1.56.56-.24 1.2.04 1.38.62.91 2.81 3.25 10.16 4.16 12.96.19.61-.11 1.28-.7 1.54z" id="h"/>
    <path d="M254.44 164.19c-.36 1.07-1.09 3.28-1.45 4.35-.18.53-.77.81-1.29.6-2.51-.96-9.08-3.48-11.58-4.44-.55-.21-.83-.8-.64-1.35.35-1.07 1.09-3.29 1.44-4.34.18-.54.77-.82 1.3-.62 2.5.97 9.07 3.48 11.58 4.46.54.19.82.79.64 1.34z" id="i"/>
    <path d="M237.5 238.35c-10.09-8.2-9.08-28.86 2.26-46.12 11.32-17.26 28.73-24.61 38.81-16.42 10.09 8.2 9.08 28.87-2.25 46.12-11.34 17.26-28.73 24.61-38.82 16.42z" id="j"/>
    <path d="M268.55 175.57c-1.13.51-3.24 1.44-4.38 1.95-.69.3-1.5-.05-1.73-.78-1.13-3.52-4.08-12.72-5.2-16.26-.25-.76.12-1.6.87-1.92 1.13-.51 3.24-1.45 4.38-1.95.69-.31 1.5.05 1.73.78 1.13 3.52 4.08 12.73 5.2 16.25.25.77-.13 1.6-.87 1.93z" id="k"/>
    <path d="M247.35 234.76c-5.23-4-2.62-18.27 5.81-31.88 8.44-13.59 19.53-21.4 24.75-17.4 5.24 3.98 2.63 18.26-5.81 31.86-8.43 13.61-19.52 21.4-24.75 17.42z" id="l"/>
    <path d="M248.97 218.74c-1.11-.9 2.26-8.12 7.51-16.1 5.25-7.98 10.41-13.73 11.51-12.83 1.12.9-2.25 8.11-7.5 16.09s-10.41 13.74-11.52 12.84z" id="m"/>
    <linearGradient xlink:href="#a" id="n" x1="308.975" y1="187.42" x2="498.657" y2="182.332" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1.09084 0 0 1 -28.066 14)"/>
    <linearGradient xlink:href="#a" id="c" x1="308.975" y1="187.42" x2="498.657" y2="182.332" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(.72767 -.38085 .34914 .66708 10.105 193.084)"/>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(-177.91 -74.04)">
    <use xlink:href="#b" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eaad22"/>
    <use xlink:href="#b" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
  </g>
  <path class="back-wing" d="M300.374 200.434s116.837-96.705 117.927-71.09c1.09 25.615-6.342 42.957-111.889 75.617z" fill="url(#c)" transform="translate(-177.91 -88.04)"/>
  <g transform="translate(-177.91 -88.04)">
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#d" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eaad22"/>
      <use xlink:href="#d" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#e" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ead822"/>
      <use xlink:href="#e" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#f" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ead822"/>
      <use xlink:href="#f" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#g" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#383729"/>
      <use xlink:href="#g" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#h" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#383729"/>
      <use xlink:href="#h" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#i" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#383729"/>
      <use xlink:href="#i" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#j" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ead822"/>
      <use xlink:href="#j" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#k" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#383729"/>
      <use xlink:href="#k" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#l" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#3e3904"/>
      <use xlink:href="#l" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#m" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
      <use xlink:href="#m" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <path d="M336.576 240.154c4.009-.5-.136 5 1.328 6.432 1.4 1.37 9.97.116 7.93 2.627-2.134 2.628-10.78 3.916-15.078 6.175-4.108 2.158-8.267 7.628-12.097 8.105-4.008.5.137-5-1.328-6.432-1.4-1.37-9.97-.115-7.93-2.626 2.134-2.628 10.78-3.917 15.079-6.175 4.107-2.159 8.266-7.628 12.096-8.106z" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M343.13 288.255c-2.381 5.955-6.17-4.324-9.066-3.485-2.768.803-7.628 13.69-9.247 8.793-1.695-5.125 3.178-18.145 3.57-25.956.375-7.465-3.366-17.74-1.09-23.43 2.382-5.956 6.17 4.324 9.066 3.484 2.768-.802 7.628-13.69 9.247-8.793 1.695 5.125-3.177 18.145-3.57 25.957-.375 7.464 3.366 17.74 1.09 23.43z" fill="#463207"/>
    <ellipse cx="332.615" cy="297.798" rx="7.196" ry="21.188" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M341.673 329.106c.457 2.686-2.767-2.585-3.492-2.412-.693.166.387 6.002-1.092 3.506-1.548-2.612-2.65-8.512-4.092-12.255-1.377-3.576-4.586-8.84-5.023-11.408-.457-2.686 2.768 2.585 3.493 2.412.693-.166-.387-6.002 1.092-3.506 1.548 2.612 2.65 8.512 4.091 12.254 1.378 3.577 4.587 8.842 5.023 11.409z" fill="#463207"/>
    <ellipse cx="351.115" cy="128.439" rx="8.237" ry="25.267" transform="matrix(.91978 .39243 -.35584 .93455 0 0)" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M254.936 313.666c-1.91-.697 1.976-11.42 2.96-16.422.984-5 .702-12.594 3.596-16.898 2.893-4.304 4.709 1.01 6.618 1.707 1.91.697 7.09-2.064 6.107 2.937-.984 5.001-6.686 10.41-9.58 14.715-2.893 4.304-7.791 14.658-9.701 13.961z" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M237.744 319.857c-2.685.462 2.58-2.772 2.405-3.497-.166-.693-6.001.398-3.508-1.086 2.61-1.553 8.507-2.665 12.248-4.114 3.574-1.384 8.832-4.603 11.398-5.044 2.686-.462-2.58 2.772-2.405 3.497.167.693 6.002-.398 3.508 1.086-2.609 1.552-8.506 2.665-12.247 4.114-3.574 1.384-8.833 4.602-11.399 5.044zM288.076 232.159c-4.008-.5.137 5-1.328 6.432-1.399 1.369-9.97.115-7.93 2.626 2.134 2.628 10.78 3.916 15.079 6.175 4.107 2.159 8.266 7.628 12.097 8.106 4.008.5-.137-5 1.327-6.433 1.4-1.369 9.97-.115 7.93-2.626-2.134-2.628-10.78-3.916-15.078-6.175-4.108-2.158-8.267-7.628-12.097-8.105zM363.99 244.882c3.917.986-1.938 4.61-1.092 6.477.809 1.783 9.252 3.717 6.442 5.32-2.941 1.676-11.467-.254-16.292.295-4.61.525-10.467 4.118-14.21 3.176-3.918-.986 1.937-4.61 1.09-6.477-.808-1.783-9.251-3.717-6.44-5.32 2.94-1.676 11.466.254 16.29-.295 4.611-.525 10.468-4.118 14.212-3.176z" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M370.502 303.896c-2.736 7.294-7.087-5.296-10.415-4.268-3.18.983-8.761 16.767-10.622 10.77-1.947-6.277 3.65-22.224 4.101-31.792.43-9.143-3.866-21.727-1.252-28.697 2.736-7.294 7.087 5.296 10.415 4.268 3.18-.983 8.761-16.767 10.622-10.77 1.947 6.277-3.65 22.224-4.101 31.792-.43 9.143 3.866 21.727 1.252 28.697z" fill="#463207"/>
    <ellipse cx="238.882" cy="419.961" rx="7.196" ry="21.188" transform="rotate(-19.343)" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M383.416 343.67c1.321 2.383-3.467-1.522-4.094-1.119-.599.386 2.353 5.536.13 3.67-2.325-1.952-5.319-7.153-7.919-10.207-2.484-2.919-7.256-6.823-8.518-9.1-1.32-2.384 3.467 1.521 4.094 1.118.6-.386-2.353-5.535-.13-3.67 2.325 1.952 5.319 7.154 7.919 10.208 2.485 2.918 7.256 6.823 8.518 9.1z" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M415.769 310.79l-13.793-6.396s7.362-1.287 18.773-11.637c11.41-10.35 9.612-31.539 9.612-31.539s5.235 7.62 6.815 11.805c1.58 4.187-2.141 18.253-6.19 23.1-5.438 5.887-8.08 10.368-15.217 14.668zM388.927 298.598l-16.93-9.215s10.423-1.573 26.58-14.218c16.155-12.646 13.608-38.533 13.608-38.533s7.813 8.509 9.85 12.224c2.236 5.115-3.232 24.5-8.964 30.422-7.7 7.193-14.04 14.066-24.144 19.32z" fill="#2d2d2d"/>
  </g>
  <path class="front-wing" d="M308.975 201.42s197.045-41.837 182.552-11.024c-14.493 30.812-33.92 46.643-178.235 20.07z" fill="url(#n)" transform="translate(-177.91 -88.04)"/>
</svg>

</div>
```

However, if you want your bee to fly to a random position and back to its starting position, you might need a little more JS wizardry. What you need is basically to set 2 timers, one that transitions the bee to a randomly generated position and another back to coordinates of 0,0:

```
let iteration = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  for (let bee of bees) {
    const tranX = iteration % 2 ? 0 : Math.random() * 340;
    const tranY = iteration % 2 ? 0 : Math.random() * 257;
    bee.style.setProperty('--tranX', tranX + "px");
    bee.style.setProperty('--tranY', tranY + "px");
    iteration++;
  }
}, _locationsInterval);
```

For this to work, your `_locationsInterval` must be the same duration as the `transition-duration` set on the bee.

The code above basically keeps track of the iteration used: if it is even-numbered, go back to original coordinates. If it is odd-numbered, go to a randomly-generated coordinates. This will create the effect of the bee going back and forth.

```js
const _wingsInterval = 500; // ms
const _locationsInterval = 500; // ms
var frontWings = document.getElementsByClassName('front-wing');
var backWings = document.getElementsByClassName('back-wing');
var bees = document.getElementsByClassName('bee');

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// update all bees' wings every _wingsInterval ms
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
setInterval(function() {
  var rotFront = -Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 5);
  for (let wing of frontWings) {
    wing.style.setProperty('--rotFront', rotFront + "deg");
  }
  var rotBack = -Math.round(Math.random() * 20 + 2);
  for (let wing of backWings) {
    wing.style.setProperty('--rotBack', rotBack + "deg");
  }
}, _wingsInterval);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// update all bees' locations every _locationsInterval ms
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
let iteration = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  for (let bee of bees) {
    const tranX = iteration % 2 ? 0 : Math.random() * 340;
    const tranY = iteration % 2 ? 0 : Math.random() * 257;
    bee.style.setProperty('--tranX', tranX + "px");
    bee.style.setProperty('--tranY', tranY + "px");
    iteration++;
  }
}, _locationsInterval);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.image-contain {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
}

.front-wing {
  -webkit-animation: flapWingFront 60ms ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
  animation: flapWingFront 60ms ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
  --tranX: -52%;
  --tranY: -26%;
  --rotFront: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flapWingFront {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(var(--rotFront)) translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
    transform: rotate(var(--rotFront)) translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
  }
}

.back-wing {
  -webkit-animation: flapWingBack 40ms ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
  animation: flapWingBack 40ms ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
  --btranX: -54%;
  --btranY: -15%;
  --rotBack: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flapWingBack {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) translateX(var(--btranX)) translateY(var(--btranY));
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(var(--btranX)) translateY(var(--btranY));
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(var(--rotBack)) translateX(var(--btranX)) translateY(var(--btranY));
    transform: rotate(var(--rotBack)) translateX(--var(--btranX)) translateY(var(--btranY));
  }
}

#bee1 {
  transform: translateX(var(--tranX)) translateY(var(--tranY));
  --tranX: 0;
  --tranY: 0;
 background: red;
 transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-contain">

  <svg id="bee1" class="bee" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 340 275" width="75" height="50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="a">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#c5c5c7"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c5c5c7" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <path d="M453.56 309.74c-11.86-45.92-22.57-71.57-55.36-100.67-21.86-19.41-40.14-15.15-54.82 12.76.16 1.03.93 6.18 2.32 15.46" id="d"/>
    <path d="M453.52 309.46c-78.71-25.57-114.71-49.86-107.99-72.87" id="b"/>
    <path d="M329.87 244.41c10.67.51 18.19-1.54 20.5-13.36 9.08-46.7-15.06-50.63-24.91-52.94-9.86-2.31-32.31-8.05-41.92-1.55-6.41 4.34-9.41 9.32-8.99 14.94 1.11 4.69 1.8 7.61 2.08 8.78.38 1.62 1.01 3.16 1.87 4.56.33.54-.81-1.33-.69-1.12 1.55 2.53 2.63 5.33 3.17 8.26 1.64 8.8 3.98 14.55 7.02 17.25 19.13 16.95 35.93 14.91 41.87 15.18z" id="e"/>
    <path d="M236.72 232.73l5.12 4.79-6.97 15.88 13.4-14.87-12.88-11.34-7.85 17.15z" id="f"/>
    <path d="M262.3 156.27c-.45 1.33-1.37 4.11-1.83 5.45a1.22 1.22 0 0 1-1.61.76c-3.15-1.2-11.39-4.37-14.53-5.58a1.358 1.358 0 0 1-.8-1.7c.44-1.33 1.37-4.11 1.81-5.44.22-.67.96-1.02 1.62-.77l14.53 5.58c.68.26 1.04 1.01.81 1.7z" id="g"/>
    <path d="M259.43 179.58c-.91.41-2.58 1.16-3.5 1.55a1 1 0 0 1-1.37-.62c-.91-2.8-3.25-10.14-4.16-12.95-.19-.62.1-1.28.69-1.54.92-.41 2.59-1.15 3.5-1.56.56-.24 1.2.04 1.38.62.91 2.81 3.25 10.16 4.16 12.96.19.61-.11 1.28-.7 1.54z" id="h"/>
    <path d="M254.44 164.19c-.36 1.07-1.09 3.28-1.45 4.35-.18.53-.77.81-1.29.6-2.51-.96-9.08-3.48-11.58-4.44-.55-.21-.83-.8-.64-1.35.35-1.07 1.09-3.29 1.44-4.34.18-.54.77-.82 1.3-.62 2.5.97 9.07 3.48 11.58 4.46.54.19.82.79.64 1.34z" id="i"/>
    <path d="M237.5 238.35c-10.09-8.2-9.08-28.86 2.26-46.12 11.32-17.26 28.73-24.61 38.81-16.42 10.09 8.2 9.08 28.87-2.25 46.12-11.34 17.26-28.73 24.61-38.82 16.42z" id="j"/>
    <path d="M268.55 175.57c-1.13.51-3.24 1.44-4.38 1.95-.69.3-1.5-.05-1.73-.78-1.13-3.52-4.08-12.72-5.2-16.26-.25-.76.12-1.6.87-1.92 1.13-.51 3.24-1.45 4.38-1.95.69-.31 1.5.05 1.73.78 1.13 3.52 4.08 12.73 5.2 16.25.25.77-.13 1.6-.87 1.93z" id="k"/>
    <path d="M247.35 234.76c-5.23-4-2.62-18.27 5.81-31.88 8.44-13.59 19.53-21.4 24.75-17.4 5.24 3.98 2.63 18.26-5.81 31.86-8.43 13.61-19.52 21.4-24.75 17.42z" id="l"/>
    <path d="M248.97 218.74c-1.11-.9 2.26-8.12 7.51-16.1 5.25-7.98 10.41-13.73 11.51-12.83 1.12.9-2.25 8.11-7.5 16.09s-10.41 13.74-11.52 12.84z" id="m"/>
    <linearGradient xlink:href="#a" id="n" x1="308.975" y1="187.42" x2="498.657" y2="182.332" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1.09084 0 0 1 -28.066 14)"/>
    <linearGradient xlink:href="#a" id="c" x1="308.975" y1="187.42" x2="498.657" y2="182.332" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(.72767 -.38085 .34914 .66708 10.105 193.084)"/>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(-177.91 -74.04)">
    <use xlink:href="#b" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eaad22"/>
    <use xlink:href="#b" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
  </g>
  <path class="back-wing" d="M300.374 200.434s116.837-96.705 117.927-71.09c1.09 25.615-6.342 42.957-111.889 75.617z" fill="url(#c)" transform="translate(-177.91 -88.04)"/>
  <g transform="translate(-177.91 -88.04)">
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#d" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eaad22"/>
      <use xlink:href="#d" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#e" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ead822"/>
      <use xlink:href="#e" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#f" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ead822"/>
      <use xlink:href="#f" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#g" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#383729"/>
      <use xlink:href="#g" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#h" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#383729"/>
      <use xlink:href="#h" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#i" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#383729"/>
      <use xlink:href="#i" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#j" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ead822"/>
      <use xlink:href="#j" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#k" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#383729"/>
      <use xlink:href="#k" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#l" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#3e3904"/>
      <use xlink:href="#l" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 14)">
      <use xlink:href="#m" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
      <use xlink:href="#m" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0"/>
    </g>
    <path d="M336.576 240.154c4.009-.5-.136 5 1.328 6.432 1.4 1.37 9.97.116 7.93 2.627-2.134 2.628-10.78 3.916-15.078 6.175-4.108 2.158-8.267 7.628-12.097 8.105-4.008.5.137-5-1.328-6.432-1.4-1.37-9.97-.115-7.93-2.626 2.134-2.628 10.78-3.917 15.079-6.175 4.107-2.159 8.266-7.628 12.096-8.106z" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M343.13 288.255c-2.381 5.955-6.17-4.324-9.066-3.485-2.768.803-7.628 13.69-9.247 8.793-1.695-5.125 3.178-18.145 3.57-25.956.375-7.465-3.366-17.74-1.09-23.43 2.382-5.956 6.17 4.324 9.066 3.484 2.768-.802 7.628-13.69 9.247-8.793 1.695 5.125-3.177 18.145-3.57 25.957-.375 7.464 3.366 17.74 1.09 23.43z" fill="#463207"/>
    <ellipse cx="332.615" cy="297.798" rx="7.196" ry="21.188" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M341.673 329.106c.457 2.686-2.767-2.585-3.492-2.412-.693.166.387 6.002-1.092 3.506-1.548-2.612-2.65-8.512-4.092-12.255-1.377-3.576-4.586-8.84-5.023-11.408-.457-2.686 2.768 2.585 3.493 2.412.693-.166-.387-6.002 1.092-3.506 1.548 2.612 2.65 8.512 4.091 12.254 1.378 3.577 4.587 8.842 5.023 11.409z" fill="#463207"/>
    <ellipse cx="351.115" cy="128.439" rx="8.237" ry="25.267" transform="matrix(.91978 .39243 -.35584 .93455 0 0)" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M254.936 313.666c-1.91-.697 1.976-11.42 2.96-16.422.984-5 .702-12.594 3.596-16.898 2.893-4.304 4.709 1.01 6.618 1.707 1.91.697 7.09-2.064 6.107 2.937-.984 5.001-6.686 10.41-9.58 14.715-2.893 4.304-7.791 14.658-9.701 13.961z" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M237.744 319.857c-2.685.462 2.58-2.772 2.405-3.497-.166-.693-6.001.398-3.508-1.086 2.61-1.553 8.507-2.665 12.248-4.114 3.574-1.384 8.832-4.603 11.398-5.044 2.686-.462-2.58 2.772-2.405 3.497.167.693 6.002-.398 3.508 1.086-2.609 1.552-8.506 2.665-12.247 4.114-3.574 1.384-8.833 4.602-11.399 5.044zM288.076 232.159c-4.008-.5.137 5-1.328 6.432-1.399 1.369-9.97.115-7.93 2.626 2.134 2.628 10.78 3.916 15.079 6.175 4.107 2.159 8.266 7.628 12.097 8.106 4.008.5-.137-5 1.327-6.433 1.4-1.369 9.97-.115 7.93-2.626-2.134-2.628-10.78-3.916-15.078-6.175-4.108-2.158-8.267-7.628-12.097-8.105zM363.99 244.882c3.917.986-1.938 4.61-1.092 6.477.809 1.783 9.252 3.717 6.442 5.32-2.941 1.676-11.467-.254-16.292.295-4.61.525-10.467 4.118-14.21 3.176-3.918-.986 1.937-4.61 1.09-6.477-.808-1.783-9.251-3.717-6.44-5.32 2.94-1.676 11.466.254 16.29-.295 4.611-.525 10.468-4.118 14.212-3.176z" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M370.502 303.896c-2.736 7.294-7.087-5.296-10.415-4.268-3.18.983-8.761 16.767-10.622 10.77-1.947-6.277 3.65-22.224 4.101-31.792.43-9.143-3.866-21.727-1.252-28.697 2.736-7.294 7.087 5.296 10.415 4.268 3.18-.983 8.761-16.767 10.622-10.77 1.947 6.277-3.65 22.224-4.101 31.792-.43 9.143 3.866 21.727 1.252 28.697z" fill="#463207"/>
    <ellipse cx="238.882" cy="419.961" rx="7.196" ry="21.188" transform="rotate(-19.343)" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M383.416 343.67c1.321 2.383-3.467-1.522-4.094-1.119-.599.386 2.353 5.536.13 3.67-2.325-1.952-5.319-7.153-7.919-10.207-2.484-2.919-7.256-6.823-8.518-9.1-1.32-2.384 3.467 1.521 4.094 1.118.6-.386-2.353-5.535-.13-3.67 2.325 1.952 5.319 7.154 7.919 10.208 2.485 2.918 7.256 6.823 8.518 9.1z" fill="#463207"/>
    <path d="M415.769 310.79l-13.793-6.396s7.362-1.287 18.773-11.637c11.41-10.35 9.612-31.539 9.612-31.539s5.235 7.62 6.815 11.805c1.58 4.187-2.141 18.253-6.19 23.1-5.438 5.887-8.08 10.368-15.217 14.668zM388.927 298.598l-16.93-9.215s10.423-1.573 26.58-14.218c16.155-12.646 13.608-38.533 13.608-38.533s7.813 8.509 9.85 12.224c2.236 5.115-3.232 24.5-8.964 30.422-7.7 7.193-14.04 14.066-24.144 19.32z" fill="#2d2d2d"/>
  </g>
  <path class="front-wing" d="M308.975 201.42s197.045-41.837 182.552-11.024c-14.493 30.812-33.92 46.643-178.235 20.07z" fill="url(#n)" transform="translate(-177.91 -88.04)"/>
</svg>

</div>
```